# 2 lists, Use Drop down to select remaining values in 1 list

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

So in this page it will show a list of what current subContractors are working on this particular BOQ. This is stored in 'allSubContractors'

This displays as a list on screen. I would then like to add a drop down box which allows the user to select any of the remaining subcontractors and add them to the list.

so far iv got the first part working, where a list of current sub cotractors working on the BOQ display but for the drop down i've got exactly the opposite of what I want.
The drop displays the same list of current Sub contractors, i want the remaining in the list.

i'm using:

```
`List<string> allSubContractors = new List<string>();
        ClarkeDBDataContext db = new ClarkeDBDataContext();
        allSubContractors = (from BoqSUBContractors in db.BOQ_SubContractors
                          where BoqSUBContractors.Bill_Of_Quantity_id == this.boqId
                          select BoqSUBContractors.Sub_Contractor.Company_Name).ToList();

        repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataSource = allSubContractors;
        repeaterShowSubContractorName.DataBind();


    List<Sub_Contractor> availableSubContractors = new List<Sub_Contractor>();
    ClarkeDBDataContext db1 = new ClarkeDBDataContext();
    availableSubContractors = (from sc in db1.Sub_Contractors
                               from bsc in db1.BOQ_SubContractors
                               where sc.id == bsc.Sub_Contractor_id
                               && bsc.Bill_Of_Quantity_id == this.boqId
                               select sc).ToList();

    DropDownListSubContractors.DataSource = availableSubContractors;
    DropDownListSubContractors.DataBind();
```

I was trying something like:

```
    List<Sub_Contractor> availableSubContractors = new List<Sub_Contractor>();
    availableSubContractors = (from sc in db.Sub_Contractors
                               select sc.id).ToList()
                               .Except(allSubContractors);
```

but noy joy, any advice?
Thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try

```
List<Sub_Contractor> availableSubContractors = 
(
   from sc in db1.Sub_Contractors
   join bsc in db1.BOQ_SubContractors
   on sc.id equals bsc.Sub_Contractor_id
   where bsc.Bill_Of_Quantity_id equals this.boqId
   select sc
).ToList();
```

?

Comment: Thank you for reply, Have tried that however 3rd line inside statement bsc.Sub_Contractor_id is saying bsc is not in scope of the left of the equals, consider swapping ( which I have just tried - and no joy) Also 'where' states expected contextual keyword 'equals'

Comment: Yeap. Change "==" by "equals", my fault ;)